# How to get objects with same key values with comma separated

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an array of objects , each object have key and value .I want if object have same keys then their values shoud be comma sepated of all the values of same key.
my html code:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in allOptions" class="item" id="{{item.id}}">
  {{item.id}} <input type="checkbox" ng-change="sync(bool, item)" ng-model="bool" >  {{item}} Selected: {{bool}} 
  </p>
```

and my controller code is :

```
 $scope.allOptions = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "data": "one",
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "data": "two",
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "data": "three",
    },
  ];

  $scope.data = [

  ];

  $scope.sync = function(bool, item){

    if(bool){
      // add item
      $scope.data.push(item);
    } else {
      // remove item
      for(var i=0 ; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        if($scope.data[i] == item.id){
          $scope.data.splice(i,1);
        }
      }      
    }
  };
```

In data array i have objects ,if we select same key of objects (same id value )then i want

```
{
          "id": "1",
          "data": "one","two",
        }
```

Comment: this might be useful for you http://jsbin.com/weyov/45/edit?html,js,output

Comment: i tired similar eg:http://jsfiddle.net/0jjquju9/8/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myData = [{
      "id": "1",
      "data": "one",
    },{
      "id": "1",
      "data": "two",
    },{
      "id": "2",
      "data": "three",
    }];

var output = [];

//Iterating each element of the myData
myData.forEach(o => {

  //Checking the duplicate value and updating the data field
  let temp = output.find(x => { 
      if (x && x.id === o.id) {
        x.data += ", " + o.data;
        return true;
    }
  });
  if(!temp)
     output.push(o);
     
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following manner:

```js
var myData = [{
    "id": "1",
    "data": "one",
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "data": "two",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "data": "three",
  },
]; // this will be your input data

function filterData(collection) {
  var hash = {};
  var result = [];

  collection.forEach(function(item) {
    if (hash[item.id]) {
      hash[item.id].data += ', ' + item.data;
    } else {
      hash[item.id] = item;
    }
  });

  for (var i in hash) {
    result.push(hash[i]);
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(
  filterData(myData) //your filtered data
)
```

Comment: can you answer what is collection      in the above code i got only object from ng-change.can you edit it to my code

Comment: See if this is helpful:
https://jsfiddle.net/devanshumadan/1hyo00fe/

Else know me your exact requirement.

Comment: i want output like {
          "id": "1",
          "data": "one","two",
        }, if we select same key value objects then array of objects with one key with comma sepated values of same key values

Comment: i found similar source of out put here please try this http://jsfiddle.net/0jjquju9/8/

Comment: Kindly check the fiddle I mentioned above. You are getting the output as you want it to be. Now use it however you want to. On checkbox click maybe.

The fiddle you mentioned is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think, easiest way to make it would be like:

```
z = [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "data": "one",
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "data": "two",
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "data": "three",
      },
   ];
```

And  immediate  code:

```
var result = {};
var groupedO = {};
for(a in z){
  var id = z[a].id;
  var data = z[a].data;
  if(groupedO[id] && groupedO[id].data){
    groupedO[id].data = groupedO[id].data + ',' + data;
  } else {
    groupedO[id] = {data:data};
  }
}
for(ind in groupedO) {
  var el = groupedO[ind];
  if(el.data.split(',').length > 1) { // here we take only last those, where many datas grouped in
    result.id = ind;
    result.data = el.data;
  }
}
```

After this, `result` will look like:

```
 { id: "1", data: "one,two" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, then you can use [$.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) function in this code if you don't want to put reference to the object **item** in array **hash**. This means that if you change the object **item** in array **hash**, then object **item** in array **myData** change too. To avoid this, use [$.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) function.

```js
var myData = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "data": "one",
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "data": "two",
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "data": "three",
    },
]; // this will be your input data

function filterData(collection) {
    var hash = {};
    var result = [];
    collection.forEach(function (item) {
        if (hash[item.id]) {
            hash[item.id].data += ', ' + item.data;
        }
        else {
            hash[item.id] =  $.extend({}, item);
        }
    });
    for (var i in hash) {
        result.push(hash[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
                                       
var filteredData = filterData(myData);  //your filtered data
```